# Navigation.goBack() with an API call in React-Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

In my application, I have few cases where navigation.goBack() cannot be used. I use react-navigation for navigation. When i'm in the detail screen, When I go back, I want to send an API call to get the latest records to the parent screen. So I used, navigation.navigate() instead of navigation.goBack(); But, this makes my app slow if I navigate and navigate back few times. It gets very slow if I do this few more times. What is the reason behind this? How the navigation.navigate() differs from navigation.goBack()?

What is the preferred way of handling this kind of scenario?

Comment: Use `DeviceEventEmitter`. send event to parent component before calling navigation.goBack()

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to pass param from navigate.goback() and parent can listen to the params and update its state?

You can pass a callback function as parameter (as mentioned in other answers).

Here is a more **clear example**, when you navigate from A to B and you want B to communicate information back to A you can pass a callback (here onSelect):

**ViewA.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, Text, View } from "react-native";

class ViewA extends React.Component {
  state = { selected: false };

  onSelect = data => {
    this.setState(data);
  };

  onPress = () => {
    this.props.navigate("ViewB", { onSelect: this.onSelect });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.state.selected ? "Selected" : "Not Selected"}</Text>
        <Button title="Next" onPress={this.onPress} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**ViewB.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "react-native";

class ViewB extends React.Component {
  goBack() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    navigation.goBack();
    navigation.state.params.onSelect({ selected: true });
  }

  render() {
    return <Button title="back" onPress={this.goBack} />;
  }
}
```

Hats off for debrice - Refer to https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/288#issuecomment-315684617